# xsl variable defined twice with same

Tags: xml, xslt, soa, jdeveloper

I am trying to generate a three digit counter like 001, 002 .... i have declared two counter variables with same name will it work?
i have defined one global variable and one within loop for incrementing counter will it generate correct values?
here is my code

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="counter" select="001"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Notes/ns0:Note">
                        <ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
                           <NOTLIN>
                           <xsl:value-of select="$counter"/>
                           </NOTLIN>
                        </ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
                        <xsl:variable name="counter" select="number(counter)+1"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Required output

```
                        <ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
                           <NOTLIN>001</NOTLIN>
                        </ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
                        <ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
                           <NOTLIN>002</NOTLIN>
                        </ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
                        <ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
                           <NOTLIN>003</NOTLIN>
                        </ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve[ showing input, your current XSLT and the expected output. Also reduce the code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i have edited my question. Reduced the code to minimum and also added the required output.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to a variable in XSLT, you have to prefix it with `$`, but that's not the main issue, which is that you cannot do this in XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="counter" select="number($counter)+1"/>
```

Variables in XSLT are immutable. You cannot re-assign a new value to a variable.

But inside your `xsl:for-each` statement, you can refer to the position of the current `ns0:Note` element in the sequence using the `position()` function, which will return `1` for the first `ns0:Note`, `2` for the second, etc.

Comment: i can't use the position() function as it will reset after each for loop iteration i have to continue the counter value through out for loop

Comment: The `position()` function will increase by 1 for each each iteration of the `for-each` loop

Comment: You're thinking of XSLT as if it were a different kind of language, where you can change the values of variables (you can't) and where one iteration of a `for-each` "loop" can affect a subsequent iteration of the same loop (it can't). When you execute a `for-each`, the `select` expression is evaluated to produce a sequence of items, and the content of the `for-each` is executed once for each item, independently, without any way to affect each other, e.g. by setting variable values. But within the `for-each`, the value of `position()` reflects the position of the current item in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You did not post an example input, which makes answering more difficult and time-consuming. Consider an input like:

**XML**

```
<Notes>
    <Note/>
    <Note/>
    <Note/>
</Notes>
```

Here you have 2 options to get the output you show:

**XSLT 1.0 [#1]**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Notes">
    <xsl:for-each select="Note">
        <ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
            <NOTLIN>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(position(), '000')"/>
            </NOTLIN>
        </ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0 [#2]**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Notes">
    <xsl:for-each select="Note">
        <ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
            <NOTLIN>
                <xsl:number format="001"/>
            </NOTLIN>
        </ORDER_LINE_NOTE_SEG>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the result in both cases is an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document because it has no single root element.

---

As already mentioned in the other answer, your attempt using a variable cannot work. Not only because a variable is immutable, but mainly because `xsl:for-each` is not a "loop": results of one iteration cannot be passed to another.

If you wanted, you could use a named recursive template to increment a counter on each successive call. But it would really be an overcomplication in this case.

Comment: @micahel.hor257k thanks for your answer i am using your second solution just one question will the counter be reset to 001 after each for loop iteration or it will be continued?

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your question. As I just now explained, there is no "loop" and no "iteration" here. When you do `xsl:for-each` you select a set of nodes; within this node-set, each node has a position accessible by the position() function.

Comment: In broader terms, XSLT is a functional/declarative language; you cannot discuss it using procedural/imperative vocabulary.